# Xamarin: Java Binding Project - Unable to change visibility of local interface

Tags: java, binding, xamarin, visibility, spotify

UPDATE: Thanks to jgoldberger I've solved this using

```
  <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.spotify.sdk.android.authentication']/interface[@name='AuthenticationClient.AuthenticationCompleteListener']" />
```

I am trying to create a Java Binding project for the Android Spotify SDK.
I have resolved most issues using Metadata.xml, but I am unable to resolve this last one.

In the SDK inside the class AuthenticationClient there is a private interface AuthenticationCompleteListener.

I have tried using

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.spotify.sdk.android.authentication']/class[@name='AuthenticationClient.AuthenticationCompleteListener']" name="visibility">public</attr>
```

and various variations including

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.spotify.sdk.android.authentication']/class[@name='AuthenticationClient']/interface[@name='AuthenticationCompleteListener']" name="visibility">public</attr>
```

however, I get the following error when building:

> error: AuthenticationCompleteListener is not public in
>   AuthenticationClient; cannot be accessed from outside package.

What can I do?

Thank you for helping out

Fred

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If that is private internal in the Java library, I would guess you should not need access to it from projects consuming the library. If so, have you tried just removing the interface in the Metadata.xml file with something like:

<remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.spotify.sdk.android.authentication']/class[@name='AuthenticationClient.AuthenticationCompleteListener']" />

or (as I am not certain of the actual fully qualified path in the java library):

<remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.spotify.sdk.android.authentication']/class[@name='AuthenticationClient']/interface[@name='AuthenticationCompleteListener']" />

Also it is sometimes helpful to decompile the Java library and look at what is really going on, path wise. On a Mac I use JD-GUI and it works well. You can just open the .jar file in JD-GUI and see the whole layout of the library. 
http://mac.softpedia.com/get/Development/Java/JD-GUI.shtml

Comment: In the end this turned out to work. Thank you for replying! In my case I had to use `<remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.spotify.sdk.android.authentication']/interface[@name='AuthenticationClient.AuthenticationCompleteListener']" />
` Thanks again.

Comment: yes @Fhl........In my case also i tried the same thing and things works fine now, Thank you

Comment: Hi guys! In my case it's not required by the library itself, but it an output type of one of public methods of another class in that library. So, it seems I can't omit it.